# Query returns different data when using MySQL versus SQLite

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

When I query the following model with SQLAlchemy, I don't get the expected result.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

I created the MySQL table directly, then committe some data:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE "users" (id INTEGER, username VARCHAR(64));

mysql> select * from users;  
+------+-------------+---------+  
| id   | username    | role_id |  
+------+-------------+---------+  
| NULL | yzxu        | NULL    |   
| NULL | after       | NULL    |  
+------+-------------+---------+
```

When using MySQL, the SQLAlchemy query returns `None`.

```
>>> User.query.filter_by(username='after').all()
[None]
```

When using SQLite, the correct username is returned.

```
>>> db.create_all()
>>> db.session.add(User(username='after'))
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> User.query.filter_by(username='after').all()
[<User u'after'>]
```

Comment: Does it work when you don't use any filter?

Comment: No.It also return [None] when I use User.query.all()

Comment: I do not completely understand the question in detail, but the problem might be related to the fact that you have two separate transactions (with different "isolation" levels when comparing MySQL and SQLite) and they do not *see* each other yet. Try to call `db.session.query(User).all()` instead of `User.query.all()` to check that.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL table was created manually by me without SQLAlchemy.  It was missing the primary key set on `id`.

Comment: Remember, `[]` is an empty list, `[None]` is a list containing one element (which is represented as the value `None`).